# Error when trying to update Oracle linux server 6.4

Tags: software-update, oracle-linux

I have downloaded this oracle linux VM:

Pre-built Virtual Machine for SOA Suite and BPM Suite 11g
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/vmsoa-172279.htmlI

In order to install the Oracle Commerce 11.1 with Commerce Reference Store
(https://www.sparkred.com/blog/installing-oracle-commerce-11-1-with-commerce-reference-store/)

But I have this error when trying to update this oracle linux VM:

> Test Transaction Errors:   file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY from install of rhn-client-tools-1.0.0.1-32.0.4.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package oraclelinux-release-6:6Server-4.0.4.x86_64

I'm more confortable with Ubuntu, so I searched how to remove the package oraclelinux-release-6:6Server-4.0.4.x86_64

but when i try this command:

rpm -e oraclelinux-release-6:6Server-4.0.4.x86_64

I got this error:

> [oracle@soabpm-vm ~]$ rpm -e oraclelinux-release-6:6Server-4.0.4.x86_64
>
> error: package oraclelinux-release-6:6Server-4.0.4.x86_64 is not installed
>
> [oracle@soabpm-vm ~]$

I don't know if there is a problem with the GPG KEY

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `oraclelinux-release`, it will cause you to be unable to use some of their repositories, or other things that the package may have come with.

But, if you insist on removing it.

```
# rpm -e oraclelinux-release
```

If it says it's not installed, run `rpm -qa | grep oraclelinux` to find it.

I don't recommend removing it though.